# Speed up for loop in R, calculating pairwise dissimilarities

Tags: r, performance, loops

I'm trying to compute all the pairwise dissimilarities between observations in a data set consisting of only nominal variables using some self-defined dissimilarity metric.

Data looks like

```
set.seed(3424)

(mydata <- data.table(paste(sample(letters[1:5], 5, replace=T), 
                        sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5, replace=T), 
                        sep = ","), 
                  paste(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5, replace=T), 
                        sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5, replace=T), 
                        sep = ","), 
                  paste(sample(letters[1:5], 5, replace=T), 
                        sample(letters[1:5], 5, replace=T), 
                        sep = ",")))

    V1  V2  V3
1: a,A E,E b,b
2: e,D C,A d,d
3: d,B B,C d,d
4: c,B A,E b,d
5: a,B C,D d,a


library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

metric <- function(pair){
    intersection <- 0
    union <- 0
    for(i in 1:ncol(mydata)){
        A <- pair[[1]][[i]]
        B <- pair[[2]][[i]]
        if(sum(is.na(A),is.na(B))==1)
            union = union + 1
        if(sum(is.na(A),is.na(B))==0){
            intersection <- intersection + length(intersect(A,B))/length(union(A,B))
            union = union + 1
        }
    }
    1 - intersection/union
}

diss <- matrix(nrow = nrow(mydata), ncol = nrow(mydata))

for(i in 1:(nrow(mydata)-1)){
    print(i)                     ## to check progress ##
    for(j in (i+1):nrow(mydata)){
        pair <- rbind(mydata[i], mydata[j])
        diss[j, i] <- apply(pair, 1, function(x) strsplit(x, split=",")) %>% metric()
    }
}
```

These loops work, but really slow when mydata has 1000+ rows and 100+ columns.

The metric I used here is Jaccard index, but a nested version. Since each element in the data is not a single value. So instead of treating each two levels as either match(0) or different(1), I use Jaccard when comparing levels as well.

**Update:**

Some context about my data, not the toy data I made up.

1. Each row represents a query, i.e. "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
   ...".
2. Each column contains part of the information in the query, i.e. 1st column contains everything between "SELECT" and "FROM", 2nd column contains what's between "FROM" and "WHERE", etc.
3. There are 100 columns and 400 rows, I don't why there are so many columns though.
4. Number of elements in one cell could be really arbitrary, some cells contain very long lists of values, while many are actually `NA`s. E.g.

   ```
                                                    SELECT
     1:                                                 NA
     2:p1.PLAYERID,f1.PLAYERNAME,p2.PLAYERID,f2.PLAYERNAME
     3:                       PLAYER f1,PLAYER f2,PLAYS p1
     4:                                                 NA
     5:                                                 NA
     6:                  c1.table_name t1,c2.table_name t2
     7:                                                 NA
    ...
   400:               asd,vrht,yuetr,wxeq,yiknuy,sce,ercher
   ```

Comment: To some extent, the slow speed is probably due to how `metric()` has been coded. If you explain the rationale behind it / what the metric does in words (in the body of the question, not in comments), it might make it easier for others to reimplement.

Comment: Thanks @Frank , that's a good suggestion. I added some description in the post.

Comment: Probably `dplyr` (which gets it from `magrittr`).

Comment: @Frank Thanks. Forgot again.

Comment: The first line of code to create mydata doesn't create the output shown.

Comment: @ARobertson I used `sample` to create `mydata`. Don't worry about different output, it's a toy dataset.

Comment: You asked question about a general concept called *profiling*. For example it is good idea to measure the time your program spent in every function. There is great probability, that only few functions use vast majority of the time. When you know that you will need to think how to avoid/recode time consuming functions.

Comment: @DaisyLee, no the problem with your toy data is that the variables are completely different than the `data.table` you list in your example.  For example, `my.data` contains a column lower case letter, upper cast letters and numbers.  The `data.table` you present you in code snippet is comprised of columns containing pairs of upper and lower case letters.

Comment: @JacobH Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: @DaisyLee, since you are comparing pairs do you even need to split at the comma.  For example, "a,A" will match "a,A" and "a", "A" will match "a","A", however the former requires less manipulations.  The only situation in which "a,A" is problematic is if you you want to match it to "A,a".

Comment: @JacobH By doing that, I can assign some similarity between `a,A` and `a,B`.

Comment: Please define a fixed seed value for random number generation with `set.seed()` before calling `sample()` for the first time. This will make your toy data reproducible. Then, everybody will use the same dataset and can compare the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain some speed pretty easily by doing less work. If you are only interested in pairwise comparisons, you only need to do N choose 2 comparisons, instead of N^2. You can implement that with `F2()` below.

```
set.seed(3424)
(mydata <- data.table(sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace = T),
                      sample(LETTERS[1:5], 50, replace = T),
                      sample(1:3, 50, replace = T)))

mydf<-data.frame(mydata)

f1<- function(){
diss <- matrix(nrow = nrow(mydata), ncol = nrow(mydata))

for(i in 1:(nrow(mydata)-1)){
  print(i)                     ## to check progress ##
  for(j in (i+1):nrow(mydata)){
    pair <- rbind(mydata[i], mydata[j])
    diss[j, i] <- apply(pair, 1, function(x) strsplit(x, split=",")) %>% metric()
    }
  }
 return(diss)
}


f2<-function(){
met<-NULL
A<-NULL
B<-NULL
choices<-choose(nrow(mydf),2)
combs<-combn(nrow(mydf),2)
  for(i in 1:choices) {
    print(i)
    pair<-rbind(mydf[combs[1,i],], mydf[combs[2,i],])
    met[i]<- apply(pair, 1, function(x) strsplit(x, split=",")) %>% metric()
    A[i]<-mydf[combs[1,i],1]
    B[i]<-mydf[combs[2,i],2]
 }
results<-data.frame(A,B, met)
return(results)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
expr  min     lq   mean median     uq  max neval
f1() 1381 1391.2 1416.8 1417.6 1434.9 1456    10
f2()  907  923.6  942.3  946.9  948.9 1008    10
```

It is a little faster, but not mind-blowingly so. My guess is that some more work needs to be done on the `metric` function you define. I tried to look at it and determine a way to vectorize it, but I could not find a way. If that can be done this problem would be trivial. For example, I have a similar program that measures pairwise cosine similarity between ~400 vectors of length ~5000. It has to make 400 choose 2 = 79800 comparisons and the entire program takes about 6 seconds to run.

Comment: I'm doing some pairwise cosine similarities as well - it takes forever. How did you structure your program? What approach did you take?

Comment: Do it in vectorized form. Define a cosine similarilty function that will compute cos similarity in vectorized form and them just work your way down all of the possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

When constructing an algorithm it is important to keep in mind the speed/space trade off.  What I mean by the speed/space trade off is that by storing your data within a different schema you can usually eliminate for loops.  However, data stored within this new schema will generally occupy more space.

The reason your example is slow is because, among other things, you are looping over all the rows and the columns of you're data.  With a 1000x100 `data.frame` that is 1e5 computations.  One way to eliminate theloop over your rows is to store you data a bit differently.  For example, I use the `expand.grid` command to combine all pairwise comparisons within the same `data.frame`, `dTMP`.  I then strip the comma and allow each member of the pair to occupy it's own column (i.e. "a,A" which is originally contained in one variable, is now "a" and "A" and represent entries in two separate variables). In general, reshaping data into different formats is quick, or atleast quicker than looping over each row.  This reshaping clearly, however, generate a data set which takes up more RAM.  In your case the `data.frame` will be 1e6x4.  Which is very large, but not so large as to clog up all your RAM.

The reward to doing all that hard work is that now it is trivial and extremely fast to obtain the `intersect` and `union` variables.  You will of course still need to loop over each column, however, we've eliminated one loop by simply arranging your data.  It is possible to remove the loop over the columns loop by utilizing 3D arrays, however, such an array would not fit into memory.

```
f3 <- function(){
  intersection <- 0
  for(v in names(mydata)){

    dTMP <- expand.grid(mydata[[v]], mydata[[v]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,c(2,1)]

    #There is likely a more elegant way to do this.
    dTMP <-
      dTMP$Var2 %>%
      str_split(.,  ",") %>%
      unlist(.) %>%
      matrix(., ncol = 2, nrow = nrow(dTMP), byrow = TRUE) %>% 
      cbind(., dTMP$Var1%>%
              str_split(.,  ",") %>%
              unlist(.) %>%
              matrix(., ncol = 2, nrow = nrow(dTMP), byrow = TRUE)) %>%
      as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


    names(dTMP) <- c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4")

    intersect <- rowSums(dTMP[,c("v1", "v2")]  == dTMP[,c("v3", "v4")])
    intersect <- ifelse(rowSums(dTMP[,c("v1", "v2")]  == dTMP[,c("v4", "v3")]) !=0, rowSums(dTMP[,c("v1", "v2")]  == dTMP[,c("v4", "v3")]), intersect)
    intersect <- ifelse(dTMP[, "v1"] == dTMP[, "v2"], 1, intersect)

    MYunion <- sapply(as.data.frame(t(dTMP)), function(x) n_distinct(x))

    intersection <- intersection + intersect/MYunion

  }

  union <- ncol(mydata)

  return(matrix(1 - intersection/union, nrow = nrow(mydata), ncol = nrow(mydata), byrow = TRUE)) #This is the diss matrix, I think.  Double check that I got the rows and columns correct

}
```

## Update

I'm still having trouble replicating your results, however, I believe the newly updated code is very close.  There is only one cell (2,1) of the dissimilarity matrix which our results differ when `set.seed(3424)`.  The problem with the current iteration, however, is that I need to implement a `sapply` to obtain `MYunion`.  If you can think of a faster way do to do this, you'll get big speed gains.  Read this SO post for suggests: [Efficient Means of Identifying Number of Distinct Elements in a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851509/efficient-means-of-identifying-number-of-distinct-elements-in-a-row)

Comment: I dont think the `diss` matrix is quite right. It returns all 1's for me.

Comment: Typo, try it now.  The diagonal is correct as it is all zeros as one would expect with a dissimilarity matrix.  The off-diagonals may need to be flipped, though I think they're correct.

Comment: It's getting closer though ;)

Comment: I see now, approach to obtaining the `dissim` matrix is incorrect.  This is because information from column 1, 2 and 3 are combined to constructed the entries of `dissim`.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to the original, but I made a few changes. It runs more quickly, but I didn't bother timing it. 1000 with this code seems about like 100 with the original.

The main changes:

- remove rbind by passing in variables to mapply calculate union
- variable instead of adding every time (union <- union + 1)
- split strings all at once outside of loops
- check length intersection before calculating union and adding intersection (lenint > 0)

Hopefully something helps your case.

```
rownum <- 1000
(mydata <- data.table(paste(sample(letters[1:5], rownum, replace=T), 
                            sample(LETTERS[1:5], rownum, replace=T), 
                            sep = ","), 
                      paste(sample(LETTERS[1:5], rownum, replace=T), 
                            sample(LETTERS[1:5], rownum, replace=T), 
                            sep = ","), 
                      paste(sample(letters[1:5], rownum, replace=T), 
                            sample(letters[1:5], rownum, replace=T), 
                            sep = ",")))

allsplit <- lapply(mydata,strsplit,split = ',')
allsplitdf <- cbind(allsplit[['V1']],allsplit[['V2']],allsplit[['V3']])
allsplitlist <- split(allsplitdf,1:nrow(allsplitdf))

metric2 <- function(p1,p2){
  for(i in seq_along(p1)){
    intersection <- 0
    A <- p1[[i]]
    B <- p2[[i]]
    if(!any(is.na(A),is.na(B))){
      lenint <- length(intersect(A,B))
      if(lenint > 0){
        intersection <- intersection + lenint/length(union(A,B))
      }
    }
  }
  1 - intersection/length(p1)
}
diss <- matrix(nrow = nrow(mydata), ncol = nrow(mydata))
for(i in 1:(nrow(mydata)-1)){
  print(i)                     ## to check progress ##
  for(j in (i+1):nrow(mydata)){
    diss[j, i] <- mapply(metric2,p1 = allsplitlist[i],p2 = allsplitlist[j])
  }
}
```